# Populate MVC Dropdownlist with multiple SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a two different SelectList (one for City and One for State). I must populate these two SelectList in a single dropdownlist with a separator between Cities and States. 
How do I populate MVC Dropdownlist with multiple SelectList's?

```
public SelectList Cities 
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
}
public SelectList State
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to bolt 2 selectlists together, why don't you combine them at source?  You've not provided much information, but *assuming* that you're using `LINQ`, and *assuming* you have a db relationship between Cities and States...

```
// get the city & state data
var cities = (from c in GetAllCities()
           orderby c.Name
           orderby c.State.Name
           select new 
           {
               cityid = c.Id,
               cityname = c.Name,
               state = e.State.Name
           }).ToList();

// convert the data into a list of `SelectListItem`
var items = from cs in cities.AsEnumerable()
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = cs.cityid.ToString(),
                Text = string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", cs.cityname, cs.state)
           };
// create the selectlist
return new SelectList(items , "Value", "Text");
```